# Github Gist в NetBeans - прямо как в Android Studio

Tags: php, android-studio, github, ide, netbeans

Я часто использую функцию создания гистов в Android Studio и хочу иметь такую же возможность и в NetBeans.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли какой-нибудь плагин для этого или другой способ это сделать? (я не нашел такого)

Если нет, то есть ли другие IDE для разработки на PHP с поддержкой гистов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/creating-gists.html) и [Intellij IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-gists.html) умеют это делать.

Comment: Которые по сути та же самая IDE, что и Android Studio. )

Comment: скорее это Android Studio - та же самая Intellij IDEA :)

Comment: Ну да, так вернее. )